# VBA Excel Incremented worksheet name Add After Statement using a stored variable sheet name

Tags: excel, vba, addition, increment, worksheet-function

How to add a worksheet in excel with VBA after a specific sheetname held by variable?

I tried:
`Set sh = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wsPattern & CStr(n)))`

The previous incremented sheetname is stored in "wsPattern & CStr(n)", The new sheetname increments up properly from another statement and variable, but the add after fails with the above syntax. I'm getting an out of range error at this line.

The code fully executes using this statement, but adds any newly created sheets from any given series at the end of all sheets:
`Set sh = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))`

As the workbook has 4 series of sheet names now (e.g. Test1, logistic1, Equip1, Veh1, etc.) that are incremented up as they are added, the next incremented sheet for a given series needs to be added to the end of that sheet name series (Equip2 should be after Equip1) and not at the end of all sheets.

```
    Sub CreaIncWkshtEquip()
    
    Const wsPattern As String = "Equip "
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim arr() As Long: ReDim arr(1 To wb.Sheets.Count)
    Dim wsLen As Long: wsLen = Len(wsPattern)
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim shName As String
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        shName = sh.Name
        If StrComp(Left(shName, wsLen), wsPattern, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            cValue = Right(shName, Len(shName) - wsLen)
            If IsNumeric(cValue) Then
                n = n + 1
                arr(n) = CLng(cValue)
            End If
        End If
    Next sh
    If n = 0 Then
        n = 1
    Else
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To n)
        For n = 1 To n
            If IsError(Application.Match(n, arr, 0)) Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next n
    End If
    
    'adds to very end of workbook
    'Set sh = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    
    'Test-Add After Last Incremented Sheet-
    Set sh = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wsPattern & CStr(n)))
       
    sh.Name = wsPattern & CStr(n)
End Sub
```

Comment: What data type is `wsPattern` ? not a worksheet is it ?

Comment: Using: Const wsPattern As String ="Equip "

Comment: I would suggest you post the code you have. _Subscript out of range_ error means that `wsPattern & CStr(n)` is not an existing sheet name.

Comment: When you add sheet `Test2`, do you have `n=1` or is it already 2?

Comment: n=1 as the stored numeric value in the string for the last existing sheet in the series to add a new worksheet after, which is correct based on the workbook worksheets

Comment: I'd still like to understand why the code I posted fails in the add after using the stored variable and works to add a properly incremented sheet at the end of the sheets by swapping the "add After" 2 lines if anyone sees where i went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function

```
Sub Demo()
   Dim s
   s = AddSheet("SeriesName")
   MsgBox s & " Added"
End Sub

Function AddSheet(sSeries As String) As String

    Dim ws, s As String, i As Long, n As Long
    With ThisWorkbook
        ' find last in series
        For n = .Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
            s = .Sheets(n).Name
            If s Like sSeries & "[1-9]*" Then
                i = Mid(s, Len(sSeries) + 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        ' not found add to end
        If i = 0 Then
           n = .Sheets.Count
        End If
        ' increment series
        s = sSeries & i + 1
        .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(n)
        .Sheets(n + 1).Name = s
    End With
    AddSheet = s

End Function
```

Comment: @Mj0915 Thanks, be aware that it will fail if series sheets are not in the correct order.